# Laravel migration can not add foreign key in user table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-migrations

I want to add a foreign key in the users table. Everything seems ok yet I get the following error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   `electro_service`.`#sql-17d0_20` (err no: 150 "Foreign key constraint
>   is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint
>   `users_role_id_foreign` foreign key ( `role_id`) references `roles`
>   (`id`) on delete cascade).

**Users**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->tinyInteger('email_verified')->default(0);
        $table->string('email_verification_token', 128)->nullable();
        $table->string('image')->default('default.png');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Roles**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->tinyInteger('role')->default(0);
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Please tell me how can I fix it and where changes will be needed.

Comment: Does roles table migrated before users table ? If no then do it and try

Comment: Maybe problem is because you run migration for `electro_service` and want foreign key from users before that table is created.

Comment: @ ViperTecPro  sir, How to migrate roles table before users table?.

Comment: @virtual Rename user migration file date to greater than roles

Answer (score 2):

Rename user migration file date to greater, than roles

example :

```
2019_06_06_135936_create_roles_table
2019_06_06_135937_create_users_table
```

Now the roles table will get created before users migration